# Disassembling instructions until 5 or more bytes returns 7 for MessageBox but 5 for similar functions

Tags: c++

I'm using a disassembler engine which is [BeaEngine](http://beaengine.org/) (I've even used HDE32 to check if it is a disassembler problem which is not)

I made this function to get 5 bytes to hook/detour any function I want.

```
size_t FHook::GetHookSize(PVOID pAddress, size_t nLength)
{
    DWORD dwOldProtect = 0; size_t InstructionLength = 0; DISASM disasm;

    memset(&disasm, 0, sizeof(disasm));

#ifdef _WIN64
    disasm.Archi = 64;
#endif

    if (pAddress && VirtualProtect(pAddress, 10, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect))
    {
        while (InstructionLength < nLength && (InstructionLength != UNKNOWN_OPCODE || OUT_OF_BLOCK))
        {
            disasm.EIP = reinterpret_cast<UIntPtr>(pAddress) + nLength;
            InstructionLength += Disasm(&disasm);
        }

        VirtualProtect(pAddress, 10, dwOldProtect, &dwOldProtect);
    }

    return InstructionLength; 
}
```

The problem is: It returns 7 bytes when I use it on MessageBox tree (All of its tree)

But for example when I try it on WSASend or send or any other API it returns 5 bytes although WSASend, send and MessageBox have same 3 first assembly instructions and same length (5 bytes). It returns on WSASend 5 bytes, on send 5 bytes but on MessageBox 7 bytes. I've tried everything possible, none is working.

I've even started to think it is a bug or something..

Comment: For the benefit of us non-Windows users, what are the, say, first 50 bytes of each function and their disassembly? And value do you call `nLength` with? Was it intentional that your wrote `disasm.EIP = reinterpret_cast<UIntPtr>(pAddress)  ****+ nLength****;`? You're not scanning from the beginning of the function if I understand right. Maybe you meant to add `InstructionLength`?

Comment: Are you *positive* you are inspecting the actual implementations and not, say, thunks?

Comment: Well, I'm using that for searching for 5 bytes length or more from the start of the API/Function I hook. I'm searching from the start of the function.

Comment: But you're not, as I pointed out. The address at which you start disassembling is not `EIP = pAddress + 0`, but `EIP = pAddress + nLength`. Did you try `EIP = pAddress + InstructionLength`? As is, in every iteration of the `while`, instead of disassembling at `pAddress+0`, `pAddress+InstructionLength0`, `pAddress+InstructionLength0+InstructionLength1`, `pAddress+InstructionLength0+InstructionLength1+InstructionLength2`, ... you _always_ disassemble at `pAddress+nLength`, which is entirely incorrect.

Comment: Oh lol, I didn't even notice that I written nLength. Thanks for noticing, it is now working!

If you can post this as answer and I will accept it! Thanks again